# Increase of Google Map API V3 speed on mobile by removing elements?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps-api-3, element

If I customize a google map from my javascript code by removing elements such as forests or lakes or others things :

will be there a real increase of the API speed especially on mobile ?

Will the map appear faster during loading ?

Are the map's movements faster as well ?

I found no article about it from the pages of google developers :-/

thanks.

Seb

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about the base Google Maps SDK-supplied elements:

No.  Not only is it not possible to disable the display of geographic features on the map, doing so would not improve performance.

This is because the Google Maps SDK displays maps by loading prerendered images.  Google's servers render the map data into PNGs that your browser simply displays.  As you drag around the map, you're really just moving the images around.  When you reach the edge of the images (known as *tiles*), the SDK loads the next set of images.

What **does** affect performance are things that *you* add to the map, like markers, info windows, shapes, overlays, and layers.

Comment: You could build a manifest however and cache images that come from Google's servers which should dramatically improve the performance on return :)